# bash parameter expansion kills gnome and kde on login

Tags: bash, gnome, kde-plasma

Under either gnome (ubuntu 12.02) or kde (kubuntu 14.04), the following simple bash script, in .bashrc, will kill the desktop on login and drop back to the login prompt.

```
echo 'Going in' >> boot.log
junk='something;for;me'
echo 'junk = '$junk >> boot.log
junk2=${junk//;/ }
echo 'junk2 ='$junk2 >> boot.log
```

The offending line, by looking at the log file, is the parameter expansion and assignment to junk2.

Under all other cases of starting a shell, it works fine.

I have confirmed that it is the same shell, /bin/bash. Don't know where else to look and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time

### EDIT

The issue is that the desktop startups do not run bash but invoke .profile, which had the bash-ism. Removing the bash-ism fixed the issue.

Comment: Rewrite your echo commands as `echo "junk = $junk" >> boot.log` and `junk1="${junk//;/ }"`.

Comment: Is your use of `junk2` and then `junks` just a typo?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That `echo` quoting change is probably a good idea (though with the code in the snippet it isn't going to make a difference) but the quoting on the assignment is almost certainly entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Well, that's just it isn't it. Nothing in the code should make any difference to the launch of either `kdm` or `gdm`. Nor would it matter if there just happened to be a global `junk` or `junk2` as they have local scope. I doubt that `junks` is globally declared, though it is the only one not in local scope. The real issue most likely has to due with any error generated causing the login shell to exit with other than a `0` exit code. That is just a `WAG`, but a reasoned one...

Comment: yes, the junks was a typo. and the quotes don't matter. the echoing is there just to confirm where the issue was. and since the second echo of junk2 never occurs, the death occurs at the semicolon subsitution. However, there is no clue as to why that is failing. Remove that line, and the login occurs successfully.

Comment: @triccare Is it certain that the lines are in .bashrc? This could be a modified bash issue. Try `bash --posix -c 'echo "${x//;/ }."'`.

Comment: Also before the line `junk2=${junk//;/ }` insert `exec >/var/tmp/debug.log 2>&`. Read the file `/var/tmp/debug.log` after running the code again.

Comment: @konsolebox: well that helped. the result is "/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 5: /home/xxx/.bashrc: Bad substitution"

Comment: I missed the number: `2>&` should be `2>&1`.

Comment: oh, and the posix option worked fine. and yes, figured out the redirect. the above is the only output. at least its a clue.

Comment: so, apparently lightdm-session is running as sh, and not bash. the $SHELL said /bin/bash which was a red herring. and i had .profile running .bashrc. so problem solved, or at least understood.

Comment: @triccare You shouldn't allow .profile to read .bashrc as .profile is a general startup file. Make .bash_profile do it instead. Is that default? What distro are you using?

Comment: so i have learned; my bad. for the moment, i've put in a check in .profile for bash shell, ala looking at ps -hp $$  i'm using ubuntu and kubunutu. the lightdm problem was found on kubuntu. doing the check for bash on ubuntu also solved the issue there. but as you suggest, i'll probably remove it totally. thanks!